# C++ Mysql Search '%Like%' error. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I tried these codes:

```
a_name LIKE %%'%s'%% ORDER BY
a_name LIKE %%%s%% ORDER BY
a_name LIKE %%s% ORDER BY
a_name LIKE %'%s'% ORDER BY
a_name LIKE \%%'%s'\%% ORDER BY
a_name LIKE \%%%s\%% ORDER BY
```

output:

```
query(adem)
```

result:

```
a_name LIKE  **0x1.37f7f4a7p-1039dem**' **0**RDER BY
```

result2:

```
' at line 1 12637743454RDER BY
```

Cause of problem %

How can i fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for `like` is a string.

You want the resulting query to look like:

```
select . . .
where a_name LIKE '**0x1.37f7f4a7p-1039dem**'
order by . . .
```

Note the single quotes around the pattern.

Here are three options:

First, pass in the string you want and concatenate the wildcards:

```
where a_name like concat('%', %s, '%')
```

Second, change the string being passed in so it has the wildcards:

```
where a_name like '%s'
```

Third, mix the wildcards with the string identifier:

```
where a_name like '%%s%'
```

I would actually propose a fourth, which is to use parameters for the query rather than munging the query string:

```
where a_name like concat('%', ?, '%')
```